# I want to place multiple paragraphs from a different document at a placeholder in my document

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to place multiple paragraphs from a different document at a placeholder in my document.

The placeholder in the final document is "{plc}".

I've tried this:

```
  var docNew = DocumentApp.openById(docNewID);
  var docNewBody = docNew.getBody();

  var docTempBody = DocumentApp.openById(docTempID).getBody();
  var docTempPars = docTempBody.getParagraphs();

  var range = docNewBody.findText("{plc}").getElement().getParent().getChildIndex();
  docTempPars.forEach(function(p2){
    docNewBody.insertParagraph(range, p2);
    var range = range + 1;
    })
```

But nothing at all is added. Can someone help out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace `{plc}` in `docNewBody` with the all paragraphs of `docTempBody` using Google Apps Script.
- From your script, there is only one `{plc}` in the document.

#### Modification points:

- `getChildIndex(child)` has the argument of `child`.

  - In this case, I think that an error occurs at `var range = docNewBody.findText("{plc}").getElement().getParent().getChildIndex();`.
- In your script, `{plc}` is not removed.
- When the paragraph is inserted, please use `copy()`.
- In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve all paragraphs from `docTempBody`.
  2. Retrieve the child index of `{plc}`.
  3. Remove `{plc}`.
  4. Insert the paragraphs.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var docNew = DocumentApp.openById(docNewID);
  var docNewBody = docNew.getBody();
  
  // 1. Retrieve all paragraphs from `docTempBody`.
  var docTempBody = DocumentApp.openById(docTempID).getBody();
  var docTempPars = docTempBody.getParagraphs();
  console.log(docTempPars.length)

  // 2. Retrieve the child index of `{plc}`.
  var element = docNewBody.findText("{plc}").getElement().getParent();
  var range = docNewBody.getChildIndex(element);

  // 3. Remove `{plc}`.
  element.removeFromParent();
  
  // 4. Insert the paragraphs.
  docTempPars.forEach(function(p2){
    docNewBody.insertParagraph(range++, p2.copy());
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [getChildIndex(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildchildindex)
- [copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#copy)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work - the {plc} gets removed but nothing is replaced. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: @bandwagoner Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work - the {plc} gets removed but nothing is replaced.`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I think that in this case, it is required to know your situation. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Google Documents of `docNewID` and `docTempID` for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. How about this?

Comment: @bandwagoner In my answer, from `I want to place multiple paragraphs from a different document at a placeholder in my document.` and `var docTempPars = docTempBody.getParagraphs();`, I understood that `docTempPars` is the paragraphs of text data. If this understanding is not correct, I think that it is required to confirm the sample Google Document. Because when I tested this modified script using the paragraphs of text data, I could confirm that the paragraphs are replaced with `{plc}`. How about this?

Comment: Sorry, this worked. I had a bug somewhere else. Cheers!

Comment: @bandwagoner Thank you for replying and test it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.